# What is the conflict in my android manifest?

Tags: android

My app is not compatible with my device SM-G350E. When I contacted Google Play Support I got this reply.

> Thanks for contacting Google Play Developer support.
>
> I’ve looked into your issue and found that your app is not compatible with the Samsung SM-G350E due to a conflict in your app’s manifest with the following feature: GPS.
>
> For more information about implied features, visit our developer site at > http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#permissions

I couldn't understand anything from the link. Please tell me what I should do? My manifest is given below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="in.mechanicapp.mechanicapp"
android:versionCode="2"
android:versionName="2.2" >
<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="4"
android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application>
.....
<application />
<manifest />
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013549/problems-wih-minsdkversion-1-5

Comment: @MSGadag That's not the issue at all....

Comment: may be device not supporting hardware location. try adding this line to manifest <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="false" />

Comment: Have you declared something like `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.gps">` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file? See AlexK answer below. You'll need to declare the `uses-feature` directives he has in his answer if you want your Samsung SM-G350E to be compatible with your app in Google Play Store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well see the link that was given to you! This is the pertinent part:

[image: link reference]

Using those location permissions implies the `<uses-feature>` tags on the right, and this implication is, by default, required. Your phone doesn't have one of the features that you're implying, so the app isn't compatible.

A possible solution would be to add this to your manifest to make the implication optional:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.gps" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" android:required="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

> your app manifest should be like this,

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.map"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<uses-feature
android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
android:required="true"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.map.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyBbdpCmoIt0TprG8iwTXnoDhkNFS8kv6XM"/>

</application>
```